# is it possible connecting to a POSTGRES database through HSQLDB

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, hsqldb

I found this template in `RC` file setup for `HSQLDB`.

**Template for a Postgresql database**

```
urlid blainedb
url jdbc:postgresql://idun.africawork.org/blainedb
username blaine
password losung1
driver org.postgresql.Driver
```

Is it possible to connect to a postgres database residing on a different server?

I have included the postgres jdbc driver in `C:\Program Files\java\jdk 1.6\lib` folder and i specified the path in `CLASSPATH` variable.

Please let me know how to make a connection to a postgres database through `HSQLDB`. Any specifications need to specify.. like `HSQLDB` server engine or any other?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me? What are you trying to achieve? Why would you go "through HSQLDB" (whatever that means) to connect to a PostgreSQL database? Just connect directly to PostgreSQL. And don't put jar files in the JDK lib directory. Put them in your application directory.

Comment: Do you want to transfer data residing in tables in a hsqldb into a tables residing in a posgrsql db? because hsqldb and prosgresql are both database systems on their own, so you want to write a program that makes a connection to each database a reads from the one and write to the other.

Comment: It's actually possible to have PostgreSQL read from HSQLDB directly using a foreign data wrapper, but I don't think HSQLDB supports reading from PostgreSQL in a similar manner. What are you actually trying to achieve with this anyway? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? Are you sure you aren't confusing HSQLDB and JDBC?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am totally confused with hsqldb, jdbc and postgreSQL. I am trying load the data residing in PostgreSQL like tables into HSQLDB In-memory database. I have the data in PostgreSQL and i ll try to load regular usage tables into HSQLDB and write some queries for the reporting purpose. is this possible.. or i need to follow a different process. If so, let me know how to achieve it. @craig

Comment: @DileepAnumala You cannot generally load a dump from one database engine (like PostgreSQL) into another engine (like HSQLDB). Look into ETL tools for data transfer.

Comment: @CraigRinger. Thank you. But what about this Template given in RC configuration file found in hsqldb zip file. It is clearly saying that we can connect to PostgreSQL right..

Comment: @DileepAnumala No. HSQLDB supports *emulating* PostgreSQL so the client talks to HSQLDB as if it was PostgreSQL and uses PostgreSQL's JdBC driver. The emulation isn't perfect. I do not know if it is good enough to let HSQLDB load a PostgreSQL dump. I would be surprised if it was.